# Who changed my weight initialization?

Tags: pytorch

I know it is the reset_parameters() in conv.py that is responsible for the default weight initialization,

I changed the function to

```
 def reset_parameters(self):
        n = self.in_channels
        for k in self.kernel_size:
            n *= k
        stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(n)
        print('reset w, stdv=',stdv)
        self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
        if self.bias is not None:
            print('reset b, stdv=',stdv)
            self.bias.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
        print('w:',self.weight.data.norm(), 'b:',self.bias.data.norm())
```

and after my model was created, I apply the follow manual weights_init() to change the weight initialization method of my conv layer

```
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        print(m)
        print(m.weight.data.norm())
        print(m.bias.data.norm())

        std_w = m.weight.size(1) * m.weight.size(2) * m.weight.size(3)
        std_b = m.weight.size(0)
        std_w = 1. / math.sqrt(std_w)
        # std_b = 1. / math.sqrt(std_b)
        std_b = std_w
        m.weight.data.uniform_(-std_w, std_w)
        m.bias.data.uniform_(-std_b, std_b)
        print(m.weight.data.norm())
        print(m.bias.data.norm())
        print('\n\n')
```

I think they are same , but I found it print below info in reset_params function.

> reset w, stdv= 0.19245008972987526 reset b, stdv= 0.19245008972987526
>   w: 4.651364750286455 b: 0.9658572124243059 reset w, stdv=
>   0.041666666666666664 reset b, stdv= 0.041666666666666664 w: 4.60668514079571 b: 0.19021859795685142 reset w, stdv= 0.041666666666666664 reset b, stdv= 0.041666666666666664 w: 6.529658534196003 b: 0.24801288097906313 reset w, stdv= 0.029462782549439483 reset b, stdv= 0.029462782549439483 w: 6.544403663970284 b: 0.20246035190569983 reset w, stdv= 0.029462782549439483 reset b, stdv= 0.029462782549439483 w: 9.237618805061214 b: 0.2699324704165474 reset w, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 reset b, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 w: 9.240560902888104 b: 0.18776950085546212 reset w, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 reset b, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 w: 9.23323252375467 b: 0.19598698034213305 reset w, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 reset b, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 w: 9.247914516750834 b: 0.19991090497324737 reset w, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 reset b, stdv= 0.020833333333333332 w: 13.062441360447233 b: 0.2709608856088436 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.058955297303523 b: 0.19297756771652977 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.064573213326009 b: 0.19342352625500445 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.060771314609305 b: 0.1931597201764238 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.068217941106957 b: 0.1944194648771781 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.064472494773318 b: 0.1871614021517605 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.065174600640301 b: 0.19473828458164352 reset w, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 reset b, stdv= 0.014731391274719742 w: 13.064107007871193 b: 0.18669129860732317

but during my weights_init() ,it print below info:

> Conv2d (3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>   2.5413928031921387
>   0.0
>   4.599651336669922
>   0.8222851753234863
>
> Conv2d (64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>   11.280376434326172
>   0.0
>   4.624712944030762
>   0.18499651551246643
>
> Conv2d (64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>   11.323299407958984
>   0.0
>   6.527068614959717
>   0.2626609206199646
>
> Conv2d (128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>   16.010761260986328
>   0.0
>   6.516138553619385
>   0.18262024223804474
>
> Conv2d (128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
>   16.00145149230957
>   0.0
>   9.22119426727295
>   0.2743944823741913 etc …

Obviously, it has been changed somewhere, for example, the bias was changed to 0 at least.
I don’t know if there another point in the source code which modify the conv weight initialization, who can explain this question to me will be much appreciated! My English is poor, hoping you can understand it :smile:

Comment: it is tough to understand what you intend to do, giving more information may help to identify the problem.

Comment: @WasiAhmad  I use the `model.apply(weights_init)` to print each parameters init value, above is my weights_init function, but is seems not the default init method I thought, I think the default method is the `reset_parameters()` in `conv.py` or `linear.py` in `nn` module, but the bias is zero here. You can refer to this [question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/who-modify-my-weight-initialization/11947/3) for a neat output info